# Can't ethernet connect to ubuntu server 14.04 using my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I achieved ethernet connection once today, under eth0, and access my PHP instance with 10.42.0.33.

However, I am now using a hotspot thingie that while charging needs to be usb connected to my computer and uses another interface *eth1*. I thought it could be conflict so I removed it, but nothing.

**ifconfig** in my server shows eth0 and lo. However, eth0 has no IP and booting shows "trying to set up network... waiting 60 more seconds to get network... booting without full network setup" or something similar. I've both ethernet ports connected, just like it worked the first time.

Whenever I try to connect to ethernet (because it shows in the networks list as "Auto Ethernet") the *wifi* symbol in the GUI bar animates in waves, trying to connect **for a long time** but fails anyway. I've tried rebooting and connecting/disconnecting devices, with no success.

Here is the `cat` of `etc/network/interfaces` on my **server**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

In my **pc**, there was no "auto eth0 (...)" part. I tried adding it but nothing still...

Can anyone please help me? I need to get my work done...